# add data to leaflet from from local file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet

I have seen many proposed solutions on the internet but none of them resolve my problem.

```
<script>
        var url = "file:///home/myusername/Bureau/metroweb/Metropolis/templates/visualization/Circular City/edges.geojson"

        // Initiate the map
        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([48.832091014134825, 2.355001022600193], 10);

        // This adds the tiles
 
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>contributors'
        }).addTo(mymap);

        var myLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
        myLayer.addData(url);
  
</script>
```

Comment: How do you expect to run this code? From a file locally?

Comment: Yes it will be from a file localy for testing

Comment: So what issue are you currently facing? Do you see any errors? Please make sure the example is a [mcve]

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: L.geoJSON is not a function`

Comment: `L` doesn’t exist in the question example code?